# Have mathematical structures equipped with "generalized relations" been considered in a systematic way?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, logic

A binary relation on $X$ is basically just a function $X^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{B}$, where $\mathbb{B}$ is the prototypical Boolean algebra $\{0,1\}.$ We can generalize by replacing $\mathbb{B}$ with a more complicated partially ordered structure. Thus, we have:

**Heuristic idea.** A *generalized relation* on $X$ is a function $X^n \rightarrow P$, where $P$ is a partially ordered set possibly having additional structure.

For example, a metric space can be viewed as set $X$ equipped with a generalized relation $d : X^2 \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ satisfying the usual axioms.

**Question.** Have mathematical structures equipped with generalized relations been considered in a systematic way? A reference would be nice.

---

*Discussion*. Here's the example I am most interested in.

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are sets, and that $R$ is a binary relation on $Y$. That is, $R$ is a function $Y \times Y \rightarrow \mathbb{B}$. Then the family $Y^X$ can naturally be equipped with a generalized binary relation $R' : Y^X \times Y^X \rightarrow \mathbb{B}^X$ defined by asserting that $R'(f,g)$ equals the characteristic function of

$$\{x \in X \mid R(f(x),g(x))\}.$$

Anyway, the point is that if $\mathcal{Y} = (Y,R)$ is a relational structure, then really $\mathcal{Y}^X$ is most naturally viewed as equipped not with a relation $R'$ having codomain $\mathbb{B}$, but rather a *generalized* relation having codomain $\mathbb{B}^X.$ We might call such a beast a "generalized relational structure."

Metric spaces presumably undergo a similar generalization, although I'm still trying to work out the details.

Comment: There are certainly category theoretic tools for talking about this sort of thing. For instance, if $F$ is the embedding $\mathbf{Set}\to\mathbf{Pos}$ and $P$ is an arbitrary poset, then $(F\downarrow P)$ is exactly the category of sets with an ordered parition. Various functors can be brought into play to add more structure; so while I know no general theory, it's certainly something nicely assimilated into known constructions.

Comment: You may be interested in [Boolean-valued models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean-valued_model) and their intuitionistic counterparts with Heyting algebras.

Comment: @Lord_Farin, thanks that looks like a good lead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've thought about that idea as well.  I don't think that there's a systematic theory along those lines.  This might mean that there's nothing to be said in full generality.  A single generalized relation is the same as a family of relations $P_i$ such that $P_i \implies P_j$ for $i \leq j$, so in some sense you don't get anything new.

You do see applications of the idea around mathematics.  Lord Farin already mentioned Boolean-valued and Heyting-valued models.  Another variant comes from theoretical computer science, and goes by the name [domain theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_theory).  Computable functions are modeled as functions on a partially-ordered set.  Functions higher in the partial order are "more defined" than functions lower.

For the specific application of metric spaces, there has been some development along the lines you have in mind.  Look for "Lawvere metric spaces".  The idea is expressed in category-theoretic language, but the underlying notion is the same as what you have in mind.

Comment: Arsmath, how is a single generalized relation the same as "a family of relations $P_i$ such that $P_i \rightarrow P_j$ for $i≤j$"? I can certainly see how a single generalized relation *whose codomain is a complete atomistic boolean algebra* can be viewed as just a family of relations (one for each atom).

Comment: If f is the function into a partially-ordered set $P$, then I have in mind the family of predicates $P_i(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ defined by $f(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \leq i$.

Comment: Thanks that actually makes a lot of sense. It also means that the homomorphisms between metric spaces are the [metric maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_map), which is cool.